# Android: Write file from other class nullpointerexception

Tags: android, filewriter

I'm trying to write a file from another class, but I get a nullpointerexception that I can not solve. The following code can be used in the mainactivity without any problems, but when I try to use it in my second class, I get the error.

```
 public void writeFile() {

    String text = "Hello world";
    String fileName = "TestFile.txt";


    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    MainActivity maObj = new MainActivity();


    try {

        fileOutputStream = maObj.openFileOutput(fileName, maobj.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();


    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass activity context instead of creating new activity instance in write method as

```
public void writeFile(Context context) {
```

and remove `MainActivity maObj = new MainActivity();` as Activities can not be instantiated this way in Android. Further, change

```
fileOutputStream = maObj.openFileOutput(fileName, maobj.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
    fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Once complete, your method should look like this:

```
public void writeFile( Context context ) {

    String text = "Hello world";
    String fileName = "TestFile.txt";

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    try {

        fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now Call your method as

```
writeFile(MainActivity.this);
```

from `MainActivity` class.

Comment: @Jullix993 Happy to help,enjoy.

Comment: This has potential to be a good answer -- after all, it is correct. Please add explanations, remove the "try" (that sounds experimental), and sum up the new `writeFile()` method.

Comment: @323go What do you mean by remove the "try"? It has to throw an exception, right?

Comment: @Jullix993, the answer included a "try to do this..." phrase, which is more appropriate for comments than answers. The answerer has removed it, which makes this a very good answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

you cannot create an `Activity` with a `new` Constructor like you did here.

```
MainActivity maObj = new MainActivity();
```

Comment: actually you can, but the android OS will not use it to make the activity life cycle , and btw this is not the answer

Comment: @SamerZuhair, no you can *not*.

Comment: @323go are you telling me that i can't say Object mObj=new Object and that's what i say you can do; or are you telling me that i can't attach 
MainActivity maObj = new MainActivity();
maObj to the android OS which i'm telling you that the android will not allow it

Answer (score -2):

change to this

fileOutputStream = this.openFileOutput(fileName, maobj.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: make sure you are in the activity class

Comment: Why would you put "this" there? Why would I refer to the class object when I need to refer to the mainactivity?

Comment: @Jullix993 if you took a look at my first comment, you would understand 

also you could check google code here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
in building the intent they wrote 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

when they actually needed a context(google convention)